# Pandas: Convert dictionary of dictionaries to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary like so:

```
d = {
'2020-07-27': {'distinct_ntwrk_cd': 127, 'distinct_inv_type_cd': 44, 'distinct_syscode': 679},
'2020-07-28': {'distinct_ntwrk_cd': 124, 'distinct_inv_type_cd': 43, 'distinct_syscode': 678}
}
```

And would like to convert it to a pandas dataframe like so:

```
+------------+-------------------+----------------------+------------------+
| Date       | distinct_ntwrk_cd | distinct_inv_type_cd | distinct_syscode |
+------------+-------------------+----------------------+------------------+
| 2020-07-27 | 127               | 44                   | 679              |
+------------+-------------------+----------------------+------------------+
| 2020-07-28 | 124               | 43                   | 678              |
+------------+-------------------+----------------------+------------------+
```

Doesn't matter to me if the date is the index or not.
What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `date` being index, you can just do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d).T
```

You can further try rename the index, and chain with `reset_index` to make `date` a normal column:

```
pd.DataFrame(d).T.rename_axis('Date').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
         Date  distinct_ntwrk_cd  distinct_inv_type_cd  distinct_syscode
0  2020-07-27                127                    44               679
1  2020-07-28                124                    43               678
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Please try

df=pd.DataFrame(d).T


            distinct_ntwrk_cd  distinct_inv_type_cd  distinct_syscode
2020-07-27                127                    44               679
2020-07-28                124                    43               678
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put the dict into the pandas DataFrame method and then swap the columns and rows using the transpose method

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(d).T
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer posted by @Quang is best solution, till now
However, if you wanna try an alternative:

```
data = [['Date','distinct_ntwrk_cd','distinct_inv_type_cd','distinct_syscode']];

for k,v in d.items():
    indices=[]
    indices.append(k)
    vals=[]
    for k1,v1 in v.items():
        indices.append(v1)
    data.append(indices)

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:],columns=data[0]); df
```